# Bi-weekly date 2011 VB6

Tags: datetime, math, vb6, datediff

I am trying to loop to get all 2011 bi-weekly dates using this code in VB6:

```
Dim HardDate As Date
Dim NumberOfDaysSince As Integer
Dim modulus As Integer
Dim DaysToNext As Integer
Dim nextpayday As Date
Dim x As Integer

x = 1
DateToday = Date
HardDate = Format(Now, "m/dd/yyyy")

Do While x <> 20
    NumberOfDaysSince = DateDiff("d", HardDate, DateToday)
    modulus = NumberOfDaysSince Mod 14
    DaysToNext = 15 - modulus
    nextpayday = Date + DaysToNext

    Debug.Print nextpayday
    HardDate = DateAdd("d", 1, nextpayday)
    DateToday = DateAdd("d", 10, HardDate)
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

However, using that code above does not produce an on going bi-weekly date...

Any help would be great!

**date example**

```
Pay Begin Date | Pay End Date | Check Date | Posts
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1/14/2011      | 1/24/2011    | 2/10/2011  | 2/3/2011
1/28/2011      | 2/10/2011    | 2/24/2011  | 2/17/2011
2/11/2011      | 2/24/2011    | 3/10/2011  | 3/3/2011
```

David

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of the first 4 or so dates that you're expecting to get from this code?

Comment: It appears that you are after *semi-monthly* dates (ie, two dates per month) as opposed to *bi-weekly* (ie, every two weeks).  I appreciate you adding the sample data, but now I'm even more confused as to what it is you want.

Comment: So you want code that will produce the 4th Thursday in Feb, the 3rd and 5th Thursday in March, and the 3rd Thursday in April?  I'm failing to see the correlation between your dates.  How many pay periods do you want in a year: 24 or 26? or 21 (as your sample dates seem to suggest)?

Comment: Thats all i know of the dates so far. we've been given checks on 2/24, 3/10 and i anticipate it will be 3/31 when we get the next one.

Comment: 3/10 is 14 days after 2/24.  I anticipate your next check will be on 3/24.  Which means @gman's code will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Updated my OP with the new pay date examples

Comment: There are 14 days between rows except for the first two Pay Begin Dates (presumably because you started part-way through that pay period) and the first two Pay End Dates (presumably because of a typo; I'm guessing that the first Pay End Date should be 1/27/2011, not 1/24/2011).

Comment: I think where you are getting confused is that you are not being paid for the two weeks immediately prior to when you are receiving your check.  This is common practice because payroll departments need a few days for processing the payments before checks are issued.  That said, the fact remains that you will receive a check every 14 days.  And that check will pay your wages for a 14-day period.  It just won't be the immediately preceding 14 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the first date you want in 2011, and you know you want 26 fortnights, the code can be simplified extremely. For illustration purposes, add a textbox "Text1" to a form, and set MultiLine = True in the designer. We'll use 1/7/2011 for our starting date:

```
Dim HardDate As Date
Dim x As Integer

x = 1
HardDate = "1/7/2011"
Text1.Text = HardDate
Do Until x = 26
    HardDate = DateAdd("d", 14, HardDate)
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text & vbCrLf & HardDate
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

The output that shows in the textbox looks like this:

```
1/7/2011
1/21/2011
2/4/2011
2/18/2011
3/4/2011
...
12/23/2011
```

Comment: Ok, i started the date on **3/10/2011** when i last day currently that payment was sent out. However, the next payday would be **3/31/2011** but that code tells me it would be **3/24/2011**?

Comment: @StealthRT: Your question asked for help in calculating a bi-weekly date (ie, every two weeks; ie, every 14 days).  This code does that.  Clearly you want something else, but you won't tell us what it is.

Comment: @mwolfe02: But that is every 2 weeks? **3/10/2011** (then 2 weeks later **(13-19/20-26)**) the **next Thursday after that** would be **3/31/2011**..??

Comment: @StealthRT: If your idea of bi-weekly is the next week after two weeks from now then, yes, that would be three weeks and this code would not work for you.  For the rest of the calendaring world bi-weekly means every 14 days.

Comment: OK i figured out the way the checks go... You are correct, its bi-weekly when the date ENDs but for some reason or another its held another week so really we get a check thats bi-weekly on **3/10/2011** on **3/17/2011**. Then **3/24/2011** we get it on **3/31/2011**.

Comment: Updated my OP with the new pay date examples

Comment: The payroll dept needs that week to process your check before issuing it.  That's a very common practice.